# linux dns server

Tags: domain-name-system

Can someone explain to me how to *easily* setup a centos 5 (64bit) dns server?

I want to use this strictly for dns for my clients who require rdns (ptr) for their domains. I do have IP delegation/authority from the data center and allocated IPs directly from ARIN.

I just want to setup a Centos 5 box to use strictly as a dns server, perhaps with redundancy with a secondary, clustered (or not) dns server

Server 1 = dns1.mycompany.com
Server 2 = dns2.mycompany.com

Then, I need simply instructions on how to create rdns records for clients upon request, *especially in bulk* amounts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.1-server-lamp-email-dns-ftp-ispconfig

http://www.brennan.id.au/08-Domain_Name_System_BIND.html

Google and TLDP is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest getting fairly familiar with bind (if that's what you choose). It's well worth the investment to pick up DNS & Bind by O'Reilly if you're going to run a DNS server.